# Expand hover area for Input Box within Menu area

Tags: html, css

I have a menu that spans the page from left to right, and when you hover on the Menu header, it displays the contents of the menu. Within one of these Menu items, I have placed Input boxes to allow the user to login via a membership number & password. If either of the input boxes have focus, then the menu will stay active.

However, I have noticed that if the user wants to use a Password management program (such as 1Password), then if they use their mouse to select an entry in the 1Password list, and the mouse moves away from the input box, the menu then disappears from view.

Is there a way I can stop this happening?

Code:

```css
#menu ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

#menu li {
  width: calc((100% / 7) - 1px);
  display: block;
  margin-top: 8px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: small;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}

#menu li a:hover {
  color: #fcc357;
  /* These are technically the same, but use both */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  /* This is the dangerous one in WebKit, as it breaks things wherever */
  word-break: break-all;
  /* Instead use this non-standard one: */
  word-break: break-word;
  /* Adds a hyphen where the word breaks, if supported (No Blink) */
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}

#menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #3c6795;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  width: calc((100% / 7) - 1px);
  margin-top: -2px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

#menu ul li ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

#menu ul li ul li a {
  font-weight: normal;
  word-break: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}

#menu li ul li a:hover {
  color: #fcc357;
  /* These are technically the same, but use both */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  /* This is the dangerous one in WebKit, as it breaks things wherever */
  word-break: break-all;
  /* Instead use this non-standard one: */
  word-break: break-word;
  /* Adds a hyphen where the word breaks, if supported (No Blink) */
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><b><a href="#">Menu 1</a></b></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/xyz/a">Menu Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/xyz/c">Menu Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/xyz/c">Menu Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/abc/a">Menu Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/abc/c">Menu Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/abc/c">Menu Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/def/a">Menu Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/def/c">Menu Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/def/c">Menu Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="members" href="#">Menu 5/a>
      <ul>  
            <form method='post' action='/hij/x.php?do=a' id='login' name='sessionlogin'>
            <div class='membership'><b>Member No:</b><br/><input type='text' name='username' size='10' class='memberinput'/></div>
            <div class='password'><b>Password:</b><br/><input type='password' name='password' size='10' class='passwordinput'/><br /></div>
          <div><input class='button' type='submit' id='loginButton' value='Log in' /></div>"
            </form>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
            <a href="jkl/g" target="_blank"><b>Menu 6</b></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you need any further information, please just shout!

Thanks!